# C# Interlocked Increment/Decrement on Native Int

Tags: c#, thread-safety, atomic, c#-9.0, interlocked

C# 9.0 introduced native sized integers ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/native-integers)). However, when trying to use these native integers with `Interlocked.Increment()` or `Interlocked.Decrement()` there aren't any overloads that allow this.

Is there a way to use native integers with `Interlocked` increment/decrement operations in C#?

Comment: You have those overloads in `Exchange` and `CompareExchange`.

Comment: @GSerg - I updated the question with clarification regarding the operations that are needed.

Comment: `nint` and `nuint` are just aliases to `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`. Because you never had the overloads for `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`, you don't have them for `nint` and `nuint` either. So nothing really changed when the aliases appeared in C# 9.

Comment: sounds like a feature request

Comment: Does it have overloads for `Interlocked.Add`?  If so, use it with `1` or `-1`.   No, apparently not; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=net-8.0 shows `CompareExchange(UIntPtr, UIntPtr, UIntPtr)` but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=net-8.0 doesn't show an equivalent `Add`.  Seems like a bad design.  You *could* write a retry loop with CompareExchange to implement atomic add/sub, but that's slower especially with non-negligible amounts of contention.